How to choose x positive integer such that x*2024^n has uneven number of digits for the longest time?
How to choose $x$ positive integer such that $x*2024^n$ has uneven number of digits for the longest time?
For example, if $x=1$, at $n=1$, I already have an even number of digits.
With $x=7$, I have to wait $n=2$.
I tried to use:
$d = \left\lfloor \log_{10} (x \cdot 2024^n) \right\rfloor + 1 = \left\lfloor \log_{10} (x) + n \cdot \log_{10} (2024) \right\rfloor + 1$
to find something interesting, but I'm not sure, I know how to deal with that problem.
If it's impossible to have a number "bigger" than a certain $n^*$, I'd be also interested to know why, preferably with undergrad mathematics tools.
tl;dr
How could I construct $x$ such that the first $n_0$ such that $x*2024^{n_0}$ has an even number of digits is as big as possible.

Do you start at $n=0$ or $n=1?$

I start at $n = 0$, so $x$ cannot have an even number of digits to begin with. $x$ cannot be $0$ either.

It looks like your final question is in the opposite direction from the text.  In the text you want to avoid having an even number of digits as long as possible.  In the question you want to have an even number of digits as long as possible.

@RossMillikan: the question says "uneven".

@TonyK:  but the question asks for the first time there are an uneven number of digits.  The text has failure at an even number of digits.

I think $n=0,1$ is the longest possible. Basically, $\lfloor\log{10}2024$ is $3,$ and the fraction part is $<1/2.$ So for $n=1,$ you need the fractional part of $\log x$ to be be at least $4-\log_{10}2024,$ and then $x2024^n$ will always have $7$ more digits than $x.$

Yeah. Your tl/dr asks the exact opposite question.

The simplest way to see is is that $2024^2$ is $7$ digits, so $x2024^2$ can have $6$ or $7$ digits more than $x.$ But you need $2024x$ to have $4$ digits more, than $x$ and $2024^2x$ four digits more,than $2024x.$

I corrected my tl;dr, sorry, that was my bad.

@ThomasAndrews Your latter comment as a proof is pretty nice thanks

When you multiply by $2024$ you add either three or four digits to the number.  You add three if there is no carry in the highest place, so you want carries as many times in a row as possible.  This will happen when $2024x$ is very high in the decade.  The next product will start with something smaller than $2024$ and you won't get a carry, so the most numbers in a row with the same parity of the number of digits is two.  You have found $x=7$, which works. Any number with an odd number of digits that starts with $5$ or greater (with more digits, $495$, which is about $10^6/2024$) will work

That's a great explanation thanks!
